# Flow control statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and practice some control flow statement,
my program is:

```
name = 'ravi'

print ('enter your username first')
Username =input()

if name ==Username:
print ('hi '+Username)
print ('enter your age')
age = input()    
if age < 18:
print ('you are not valid Kido')
elif age > 2000:
print('Unlike you, Alice is not an undead, immortal vampire.')
elif age > 100:
print('You are not Alice, grannie.')
elif age>=18:
print ('Welcome in our portal')
```

Every time I run this code it conduct an error:

```
enter your username first
ravi
hi ravi
enter your age
18
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\NEWpASSWORD.py", line 11, in <module>
    if age < 18:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Read the linked question, Ravi. The issue here is that you're comparing the result of `input()`, a `str`, with an `int` in `if age < 18:`. The question linked explains how to read ints with `input`.

Comment: than i got i after your suggestion i used age=int(input()) and it working fine

Comment: Could you explain what you mean, Ravi?

Comment: I just wanted to say that my its is working now with your suggestion.